# tikz: contour line on inner side of rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw two rectangles with different linewidths, but the same (outer) height. This code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thin](0,0)rectangle++(-1,1);
\draw[line width=2mm](0,0)rectangle++(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

results in:

[image: different height]

How can I tell tikz to draw the contour only on the inner side of the specified coordinates to achive the following picture?

[image: same (outer) height]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any option allowing that but here are two ways to achieve it by clipping or explicitely filling the border:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}\path[clip, postaction={draw, line width=3mm}] (-1,0) rectangle ++(1,1);\end{scope}
\begin{scope}\path[clip, postaction={draw, line width=1mm}] (0,0) rectangle ++(1,1);\end{scope}

\fill[even odd rule] (0,-2) rectangle ++(1,1) (.2, -1.8) rectangle ++(.6,.6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```